# Multiply Columns Based on Condition and Put Comma Separator Using R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. Based on a condition -- millions or thousands present in a text -- I need to multiply the numeric column with million or thousand, and then put a thousand separator:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c('', 'assets', 'loss', 'liability'),
                 col2=c(NA, 5000, -1400, 300),
                 col3=c(NA, 4500, -1100, 500))

df

col1        col2    col3
<chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
             NA      NA
assets      5000    4500
loss       -1400   -1100
liability   300      500
                                                                  ​               ​        ​
```

I am trying the following script to see which condition -- million or thousand -- is present, multiply with that, and then put a thousand separator:

```
multiply_columns <- function(df){

  text <- "in millions, except share and per share data"

  # Iterate over the columns
  for (idx in 2:length(names(df))) {
      
      # Check if text contains million
      if (grepl(text, "in millions", fixed = TRUE)) {
        
        # If yes, multiply column values with million else thousand
        df[, idx] <- format(df[, idx]*1000000, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)
      
      } else 
        df[, idx] <- format(df[, idx]*1000, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)
}  
  return(df)
}
```

It seems the function isn't multiplying correctly. It's multiplying with 1000 whereas the text contains millions.

```
multiply_columns(df)

col1             col2          col3
<chr>           <chr>          <chr>
                 NA            NA
assets        5,000,000     4,500,000
loss         -1,400,000    -1,100,000
liability     300,000       500,000
```

**Desired Output**

```
col1             col2           col3
<chr>            <dbl>          <dbl>
                  NA             NA
assets        5,000,000,000   4,500,000,000
loss         -1,400,000,000   -1,100,000,000
liability     300,000,000     500,000,000
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `if (grepl(text, "in millions", fixed = TRUE)) {` :  here the pattern "in millions" go first (`grepl("in millions",text,  fixed = TRUE)`). Is it ok that you modify all columns based solely on "text" ?

Comment: Except the 1st column, modify all. It seems it works if I change the position of pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may extract the `thousand`, `million` and replace with `1e3` and `1e6` to multiply.  Assuming that the `text` can be input to the function

```
library(dplyr)
multiply_columns <- function(df, text){

 val_to_mult <- as.numeric(stringr::str_replace_all(stringr::str_extract(text, 
      "million|thousand|billion"),  setNames(c("1e3", "1e6", "1e9"), 
            c("thousand", "million", "billion"))))
 df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ scales::comma(.x * val_to_mult)))
    }
```

-testing

```
> text <- "in millions, except share and per share data"
> multiply_columns(df, text)
     col1           col2           col3
1                     <NA>           <NA>
2    assets  5,000,000,000  4,500,000,000
3      loss -1,400,000,000 -1,100,000,000
4 liability    300,000,000    500,000,000

> multiply_columns(df, "in thousands")
    col1       col2       col3
1                 <NA>       <NA>
2    assets  5,000,000  4,500,000
3      loss -1,400,000 -1,100,000
4 liability    300,000    500,000

> multiply_columns(df, "in billion")
    col1               col2               col3
1                         <NA>               <NA>
2    assets  5,000,000,000,000  4,500,000,000,000
3      loss -1,400,000,000,000 -1,100,000,000,000
4 liability    300,000,000,000    500,000,000,000
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, this looks so dynamic. Much appreciated. What if, only the dataframe is the input argument, not the text?

Comment: @Roy You can have it inside the function.  I showed an extra argument 'text' so that I can test on different inputs easier.  The change will be just like `text` inside as you showed it inside the function and remove the `text` argument from the function

Comment: Happy new year @akrun. I want to use this function for only 2 columns. One column has several variations -- `fair value`, `FairValue`, `value`. Another column has variations -- `AmortizedCost`, `amortized cost` and `cost`. How can we approach that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @akrun. This is such a great function. I'm using it for other functions too. If you don't  mind, would you please explain how the `setnames` part works. Also, if I want to use this function to a list of columns, is this right -- `dataframe %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(col_list), ~ scales::comma(.x * val_to_mult)))`?

Comment: @Roy You are right.  With `setNames`, we are creating a named vector with the names being the patterns to match and the values being the 1e3, 1e4.  Thus, when it matches those patterns in the column, it returns the 1e3, 1e4 whereever it matches

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with tidyverse functions, but here is how I would structure your function:

```
library(tidyverse)

conv_th_or_mm <- function(df, text){

  if(str_detect(text, regex("million", ignore_case=T))){

    df <- df %>%
      mutate(
        across(
          .cols = where(is.numeric),
          .fns = ~.x*1000000
        )
      )

  } else {

    df <- df %>%
      mutate(
        across(
          .cols = where(is.numeric),
          .fns = ~.x*1000
        )
      )

  }

  df <- df %>%
    mutate(
      across(
        .cols = where(is.numeric),
        .fns = ~formatC(.x, big.mark=",", digits=0, format="f")
      )
    )

  return(df)
}
```

A few points:

- I added `text` in as an argument of the function, which I think you will want to pass in depending on the dataframe.
- I've only used formatC() before, so I've used equivalent parameters to match your format() function.
- I gave your function a slightly different name, which maybe isn't important now but could be if you next look at it a year from now and there are two dozen other functions you've written.
- If your use case calls for it, you could be more specific with .cols but I assumed all the numeric values needed to be converted.

Editing to add that R is very flexible for where it goes to look for variables you call. It is possible that R could go look for `text` in the global environment if you call it within your function despite not passing it in as an argument (which is strange behavior for some other languages). However, if the data outside of your function is my_df and your text you're evaluating is my_text, you would use my function like this:

```
my_df <- conv_th_or_mm(df = my_df, text = my_text)
```